PDE Terminology
The solution $u:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to a given PDE on the set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is called classical, if $u$ is differentiable on $\Omega$ and $u$ satisfied the PDE $\textit{identically}$ on $\Omega$.
What does identically mean in this context?

Your text says that is a "Classical Solution" , hence you should include the other types of Solutions here. That might give you easy clues on what that means.

It just means that the PDE is satisfied at every point in $\Omega$.
The terminology comes from situations where one wants to distinguish equations $f(x)=g(x)$ which hold only for particular (sought) values of $x$ from identities $f(x)=g(x)$ which hold for every value of $x$; in the latter case one then says that $f(x)$ is identically equal to $g(x)$, and this is sometimes written as $f(x) \equiv g(x)$.
(See this question, for example, and several other similar ones.)
